# jquery .css() .attr() i tried every thing

Tags: jquery, css

```
#centerdiv {
    position:fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#errorcenterdiv {
    position:fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em;
    margin-left: -15em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Can some one tell me WHY i can't get this work on jquery i don't know i start believe that there is something wrong with the css code that i don't recognize .

Comment: What behavior do you want, and what actually happens?

Comment: Please post your markup and javascript. We need to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your question contains a bunch of CSS.  Your title talks about jQuery.  You don't show us the HTML or tell us what is and isn't working.  As your question stands now, there is NOTHING we can do to help because you haven't supplied enough information for anyone to know how to help.  Is this a jQuery question?  Is this a pure CSS question?  What's the expected result?  What kind of result are you seeing?

Comment: btw, those styles are exactly the same, you may want to try using a class instead.

Comment: What you ask is not clear, can you more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to add styles dynamically, use IDs to reference but classes to add the style. using IDs to append styles can have unexpected consequences (no styles applied)

so if you want a centered div

```
<div id="centerMe">stuffing</div>
```

just reference via ID (centerMe), and add a class (centerDiv):

```
$('#centerMe').attr('class','centerDiv');
```

or

```
$('#centerMe').addClass('centerDiv');
```

your css rule should have the "dot" (.) instead of "hash" (#)

```
.centerdiv {
    position:fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the question is not clear , but according to the title i assume you are looking for a code of applying a css class to a div via javascript .

Here's the code

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">abc</div>
```

And here the jQuery

```
$("#mydiv").attr("class", "mynewclass");
```

Comment: @nnnnnn , you are right , but if he needs to switch the class again , the new class will not replace the old class , they will be merged , then he has to clear the class before applying the .addClass()

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking your CSS symbols.  The pound sign (`#`) is to apply those styles to the corresponding `id` in the markup.  If you are looking for classes, you'd do something like:

```
.centerdiv { 
    position:fixed; 
    top: 40%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width:30em; 
    height:18em; 
    margin-top: -9em;  
    margin-left: -15em; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color: #f3f3f3; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
} 

.errorcenterdiv { 
    position:fixed; 
    top: 40%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width:30em; 
    height:18em; 
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color: #f3f3f3; 
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
}
```

And then you would use jQuery to set them, like so:

```
$('div#someId').addClass('centerdiv');
```